# How to call while loop after it ends

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a do...while loop in my code, and I'm kind of stuck with it.
The problem is that the condition is a comparison between two arraylist, so it runs the first time, and then the condition returns false, but after that i add number(s) to one of the arraylist (while the program is running of course) which makes both arraylist to be equals, and now i would like to continue with the loop , but i have no idea how to do this.

Any suggestions will be appreciated :)

```
do{...} while(ArrayList1.equals(ArrayList2));
```

Comment: what do you mean by `which makes both arraylist to be equals`, you mean their size are equal?

Comment: You need to find a different condition to stop the loop then. If you want the loop to run even if the lists are not equal, then you can't have that be the condition on which to stop.

Comment: You are comareing `ArrayList1.equals(ArraList2)`. Have you override the equals method?

Comment: no, it makes them exactly the same, the same numbers in both

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered nesting this loop into another one? This way you can go through it again and exit the outer loop on some condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Once a loop ends, the following statements will be evaluated and the loop will not be revisited, even if the condition is true. You might want to add an element *inside* the loop

Answer (score 0):

You would end up with a infinite loop if you achieve this condition. Not able to understand why you want to achieve this logic.

To achieve this, You could extract out do..while loop into a separate private method to which you pass in the two ArrayList as arguments. (Depends on what other details you require within your loop.) Call this method twice with the logic of adding elements to one of the list in between the two calls. Something like

```
private void executeDoWhile(List arrayList1, List arrayList2)
{
  do{ ....   } while (arrayList1.equals(arrayList2);
}

main()
{
....
//call 1
executeDoWhile(arrayList1, arrayList2);

//logic to add the elements

//call 2
executeDoWhile(arrayList1, arrayList2);
}
```

Comment: after the 2nd runing of this loop the arraylist will change again.. it's like a memory game, kind of Simon Says. maybe i will find another way to apply this game to work